# Identity Token is NOT required for PayPal's Payment Data Transfer (PDT)?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've setup a PayPal site which uses IPN and I was having trouble getting PayPal to send the GET variables to the return URL that I had specified. It was sending the user's browser to the return URL, but nothing was being passed via GET or POST.

I changed one setting in the PayPal business account: "Payment Data Transfer (optional)" to On which generated an "Identity Token" on the PayPal website.

I also got an automated email from PayPal saying:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: service@paypal.com <service@paypal.com>
Subject: Payment Data Transfer (PDT) Has Been Enabled

This email is to inform you that you have successfully enabled Payment Data Transfer.

PDT's primary function is to display payment transaction details to buyers when they are redirected back to your site upon payment completion. However, there are cases, such as with pending transactions, where you won't receive notification of all transactions. For this reason, PayPal strongly recommends that you also enable Instant Payment Notification (IPN).

To learn more about enabling and setting up IPN:
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=p/xcl/rec/ipn-intro-outside

To learn more about Payment Data Transfer, including setup instructions and a complete list of variables:
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-intro-outside

Sincerely,
PayPal
```

Clicking on the second link and clicking on "Technical Overview" (https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-techview-outside) shows:

> Your POST should be sent to
>   https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.
>   You must post the transaction token
>   using the variable "tx" and the value
>   of the transaction token previously
>   received (e.g.
>   "tx=transaction_token"), and the
>   special identity token using the
>   variable at and the value of your PDT
>   identity token (e.g.
>   "at=identity_token"). You will also
>   need to append a variable named "cmd"
>   with the value "_notify-synch", for
>   example "cmd=_notify-synch", to the
>   POST string.

However, I am NOT passing the Identity Token at all, yet everything is working fine!

```
(a) Is this a problem?
(b) Why is it working if the documentation implies that it shouldn't?
(c) Is this a consequence of specifying an outdated API version (58.0)? What is the value I should be using?
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the identity token should be a required param since it is the only way Paypal can verify that the request you're making is valid. Otherwise, other people can simply guess a transaction id (even though it is not intended for their accounts) and get details for that transaction from Paypal.

I'm guessing this is a bug you're experiencing. Are you testing in the Paypal sandbox or in a live environment?

Answer (score 1):

Realizing that the OP probably no longer needs an answer after 9 years, but others still might:

The POST of the transaction ID and identity token is purely for the purpose of verifying that the original transaction notification (relayed via the GET method to the merchant's Return URL) actually came from PayPal.

It is as if to say to PayPal, "My website just got this supposed confirmation that a customer paid. Here is the transaction ID and my seller ID again. Is this a legitimate match?"

In fact, at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/payment-data-transfer/, when talking about setting up for testing, it only talks about getting your script ready to receive, parse and display the GET data. It doesn't mention the POSTing back to PayPal (though that is mentioned elsewhere). So, yes, the PDT function should work without doing the POST back to PayPal afterward and waiting for that response of SUCCESS or FAIL, but...

Anyone who knew what they were doing could go to a seller's URL and append a query string with the right combination of variables to fake the same kind of GET request that the PayPal PDT system would initially send, whether or not the transaction ID were a real one.